# How do I get my desktop Icons back on my primary display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, ubuntu-mate, desktop-icons

So, I have read several questions - with and without answers - and though this is similar to others, I have found nothing particular to the issues I am experiencing. It is a three-part problem and I think they're all related erego why they are being posed as a single question.

1. My desktop icons are all on my secondary display and I can't move them back.
2. I can no longer maximize windows on my primary display by dragging them to the top of the screen, this results in them being dragged to a desktop with no display that shouldn't be an accessible area anyway.
3. After hours of searching for solutions, I was finally able to write a script that will create and assign the proper resolution and position to my secondary display, and leave it alone if it isn't connected. The catch there is that I have to log in first, so prior to login I am stuck with a sideways login screen that is, oddly enough, on my secondary display.

I am using an older VAIO laptop with a VGA output (hence the need to create the proper resolution for my external monitor) and running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

Here's a screen shot:

[image: Monitor layout, icons, and example of window problem]

And here's my script: feel free to do whatever you want with it. It may be of use to people with display configuration issues.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --auto
cvt 1920 1080
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --rotate right
xrandr --output LVDS1 --pos 0x1281 --output VGA1 --pos 1281x0
xrandr --auto
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this in in Display settings (System Settings --> Display). The three monitors I use are different sizes, but after dragging the monitors so that they were aligned along the bottom axis, my icons returned my primary monitor on the left

Like this

[image: Display settings]

Comment: Hmm, I had problems with this, snapping didn't allow them to be aligned.  I used `arandr` to fix alignment, but sadly icons still refuse to stay on my laptop screen.

Answer (score 3):

I am running Gnome and have a dual monitor setup.  If I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> a menu pops up on my primary display and "Move to Monitor Right" or "Move to Monitor Left" is highlighted.  Click that selection and the icons move to the other screen.

Comment: the problem was the icons showing up on the secondary display and not being able to put them on the primary. I never figured it out, but I switched flavors to Ubuntu Gnome and that fixed everything and more.

Comment: This caused my icons to disappear, how can I bring them back to one monitor at least?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the [iconic script](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) to give control over which monitor icons are placed on. It also ensures icons don't get placed into the "black hole" that exists when monitors of different resolutions are used.

Here are a few screenshots of `iconic` to give you an idea of how it works.

#### iconic Monitors Notebook General Tab screenshot

[image: iconic monitors general.png]

On this notebook tab you can also specify the number of seconds a test will last. Press the <kbd>Test</kbd> button to place icons on the Desktop using currently defined each time you change the reserved screen space.

#### iconic Monitors Notebook Monitor 3 tab

[image: iconic monitors monitor 3.png]

Assign a user friendly name to each monitor. Set the number of rows and columns to utilize for icon placement on each monitor.

Use the <kbd>Test</kbd> button to view what icon placement after number or columns and/or rows are changed.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I solved this problem by duplicating desktop icons in the desktop folder: link1, link2,... and link1(copy), link2(copy), for instance. Then I place the duplicate icons as I wish in the two desktops with respect to the two monitors. Everything is fine even if I do monitor manipulations or reboot, etc...

In your case, if you have three monitors, you need three links for the same thing in the desktop folder.

Comment: I don't think OP wants the icons to appear on each monitor, just on the primary one...

Answer (score 0):

solved, right click on task-bar, under taskbar tab (box that opens) under 'multiple displays' panel, tick 'Show taskbar on all displays' -> in drop down box below box you just ticked is called ' Show task bar buttons on:' select 'All taskbars'.  click apply,

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this and couldn't find an answer through searching. However, I discovered that the [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://linuxhint.com/gnome-tweak-tool-ubuntu-17-10/) took care of this. Just open the Desktop tab, and turn Icons off and on.  They jumped right back to the left hand, primary monitor.  Plus there are lots of other good tweaks in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Ugly fix' works well.

- **File Manager > Desktop >**
- In this file manager don't hesitate to resize the window to fit the icon to your liking.
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all icons
- Then drag&drop into your desktop display of you choice.

Comment: this duplicate my content XD

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with “Lock panel/Unlock panel”

My panels were locked, and when I have added additional display to mu configuration, all locked panels stayed on new display.

I did:

1. unlock all panels
2. move them to my preferred display
3. lock them again
4. save display configuration

that helped.

Answer (score -1):

**The Issue**

Icons stay in the top blank black spot of the smaller display (usually laptop)

[image: screenshot]

✅ **Ugly Fix**

**File Manager** > **Desktop** > *Drag icons to the smaller display & they will relocate*

- Pros: Very quick
- Cons: Repeat every time a new icon is added